# Xcode convert rawdata from 8 bit/channel to 16 bit/channel using apple native framework

Tags: xcode, macos, image, cocoa, core-graphics

I have rgb raw data, which is 8 bit/channel, i need to convert it to 16 bit /channel, any native framework can do so, thanks.

so input is image width, height, rawdata, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to convert 8bpc raw image into 16bpc raw image (without any special color processing and filtering) - you don't need any special framework. You can do it by youself by conbverting pixel by pixel... In case of unsigned short 16 bit raw conversion will looks like:

```
size_t ent_cnt = width*height*channel_count;
unsigned short *dst = new unsigned short[ent_cnt];
unsigned short *dst_ptr = dst;
unsigned char *src_ptr = src;
while (ent_cnt --)
    *dst_ptr++ = (unsigned short)(*src_ptr++) << 8;
return dst;
```